How to show Blade view from within Livewire handler
Has Livewire component with wire:click="toggleChecked" clause and this handler is:
public function toggleChecked(): void
{
    (new ScaleController())->index();
}

I want to show welcome screen by this handler.
Controller code is trivial:
class ScaleController extends Controller
{
    public function index(): mixed
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }
}

I use this method (index) in route, so it's working itself.
But when I call it from Livewire handler - code executed (checked by interactive debug), but no visual changes shown.
How to get visual changes from Livewire handler?

You're doing it all wrong. Let's start from the basics.
Never use new Controller.
// Livewire component

use Livewire\Component;

class Show extends Component
{
    public bool $show = false;
    
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.show');
    }
}

// Livewire view

<div>
    <button wire:click="$toggle('show')">
        Show welcome
    </button>

    @if($show)
        @include('welcome')
    @endif
</div>

https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/actions#toggle

It's seems a good idea to control visual behaviour in ONE component boundaries. I'm using this approach, of course. But my goal is to show ANOTHER Blade view
